# How to add framework to an Android Studio Project?

Tags: android, android-studio, templates, frameworks

I want to work on a framework so that I was following this tutorial. https://medium.com/@kmmraj/android-clean-code-part-1-c66da6551d1

It says to download and locate the framework which I did.

I have added the template to the **{ANDROID_STUDIO_LOCATION}/plugins/android/lib/templates/other/** location as the documentation said.

However after this point I do not know how to add this framework to my existing project. Or how am I supposed to use it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am still waiting for some help.. thanks

Comment: Any suggestions?